# Fatima: different ways of pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, word-stress

How should the feminine name Fatima be pronounced? Which syllable should be stressed? (I know that sometimes it is pronounced as Fat - ***i*** - ma, with the second syllable stressed.)

Comment: I've generally heard it pronounced **FAA-teh-maa**, with the stress on the first syllable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about learning English.

Comment: Have you tried googling it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatima_(given_name)

Comment: @JavaLatte If Google had given only one variant of pronunciation, I wouldn't have asked my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Cambridge English Pronunciation Dictionary, this three-syllable word is always stressed on the first syllable (FA.) in British English, but in American English, it can be stressed on either the first (FA.) or the second (TI.) syllable.

Answer (score 4):

The best answer is, "However Fatima *wants* her name pronounced".

One of the many challenges living in American multiculturalism is the extreme diversity of names, from every country on Earth.  If you're the kind of American who cares about such things (which is not every American, but that's off-topic) you learn to pronounce these names as they would be spoken in their "native" language, country, or culture.

Of course many who live here just adopt nicknames if their actual name is too problematic.  I know a friend of a friend whose name is Xavier, but he just asks people to call him "Chavi" because getting people to pronounce "X" as "Ch" (like the IPA ["voiceless velar fricative"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_velar_fricative)) gets tiresome.

So if we're introduced and I hear "FAH-ti-ma" I say that.  If she says "fa-TIH-ma" that's what I say.  The same name -- such as "Julia" -- can be spelled the same but sound different depending on who it belongs to.